# reportlab save location

Tags: python, location, save, reportlab

I am trying to save a PDF file generated by reportlab to a specific location. Is it possible? Code creates the pdf to its own directory.

```
def myFirstPage(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Bold',16)
    canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT-108, Title)
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman',9)
    canvas.restoreState()

def create_pdf(sometext):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("myfile.pdf")
    Story = [Spacer(1,2*inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]
    bogustext = ("There is something: %s. " % sometext)
    p = Paragraph(bogustext, style)
    Story.append(p)
    Story.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))
    doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=myFirstPage)
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible. I recommend using [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build up the path. Example:

```
import os

def create_pdf(sometext):
    outfilename = "myfile.pdf"
    outfiledir = '/somedir'
    outfilepath = os.path.join( outfiledir, outfilename )
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate( outfilepath )
    # ...
```